# In Java, how to change the color of a button, wait a few second, then change it again?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jframe, jbutton

My problem:
I have a JButton. When I click, the color of button will change to red. After that 3 seconds, the color will change to blue.
Please, help me. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Timer, it helps you wait 3 seconds

Answer (score 4):

Suggestions:

- In the button's ActionListener, set its color to Color.RED via the `setBackground(...)` method.
- In the same ActionListener, start a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to change the color back to Color.BLUE, again using the `setBackground(...)` method.
- Give it a delay of 3000 (milliseconds = 3 seconds).
- You will want it to run just once, so you will call `setRepeats(false)` on it before calling `start()`.
- [Link to Swing Timer Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).
- If you need more detailed help, then please show pertinent code, preferably an [sscce](http://sscce.org), and ask a more detailed and informative question.

Comment: +1 for effectively helping while at the same time encouraging self-effort.